# Ftp connection working on emulator but not on actual device

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons

I've written an FTP service for Android, using Apache Commons-net 3.3.

When I run it on the emulator (with sdks 17 and 8, i.e. Android 2.2), all goes right; but when I run it on a LG P350, which mounts Android 2.2, the following code throws a `SocketException` with a timeout message:

```
ftp.connect(host, port);
```

where ftp is an istance of FTPClient. Arguments are: 192.168.0.100 (my notebook IP address) and 21 respectively.

I repeat: the same code is working under the emulator, and my phone is WiFi connected to the same network of my PC, pinging each other.

Someone can guess what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try connect to your Pc's Ftp port different apps ? Maybe you should change your router firewall settings. Because when you try from Emulator, it's connect same Ip address but when you use your phone this request goes on the router.

I think, firstly you can try with this apps connect your Pc. I believe that you can't reach your Pc. Try and share  what it do please..

You can use this apps..

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glasertech.android.nettools&hl=tr

Comment: Interesting... I guess you're right. I've tried AndFTP, a free app on the Market, and my server doesn't receive any connection attempt, like with my App. I can't access as admin to my router, so I'll try with another network in a few days. Thank you, in the meanwhile.

Comment: I succeded with an online FTP server, so the problem is my wan... but I still can't figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Is your phoe rooted?
Otherwise I think that you are not allowed to do that on your device.

Try a port above 1024. 
Probably this will fix it.